# How to change class atribute of a tag and apply styles without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to enchance the layour of my navigation menu bar.

Want I would want to acomplish is having a class style "active" for the item in the menu that is active, that means we clicked on it. The style for class "active" only highlights in blue the item in the navbar (the others "inactive" remain grey).

I tried using the onlick attribute that calls a JavaScript function **makeActive()** that changes the class of the clicked button of menu and changes all other classes of the navbar to "inactive".

However I think I'm missing something about the DOM or AJAX because the styles doesn't change the layout of the active button remains the same.

PD: I would want to archive this in purely **vanilla JavaScript** (not JQuery).

**styles.css:**

```
/* NavBar */

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: rgb(49, 149, 250);
    color: white;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Travel Agency</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

        <script>

            function makeActive(id)
            {
                var ancestor = document.getElementsByClassName('topnav');
                var descendents = ancestor[0].getElementsByTagName('*');

                for(var i = 0; i < descendents.length; i++) {
                    if (descendents[i].className === "active" && descendents[i].id != id) {
                        descendents[i].className = "inactive";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for(var i = 0; i < descendents.length; i++) {
                    if (descendents[i].id = id) {
                        descendents[i].className = "active";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a class="active" id="home" href="#home" onclick="makeActive('home')">Home</a>
            <a class="inactive" id="offers" href="#offers" onclick="makeActive('offers')">Offers</a>
            <a class="inactive" id="travels" href="#travels" onclick="makeActive('travels')">Travels</a>
            <a class="inactive" id="galery" href="#galery" onclick="makeActive('galery')">Galery</a>
            <a class="inactive" id="contact" href="#contact" onclick="makeActive('contact')">Contact</a>
            <a class="inactive" id="about" href="#about" onclick="makeActive('about')">About</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Solved! I forgot a double === in the function makeActive and is working.

Now the function is:

```
function makeActive(id)
{
    var ancestor = document.getElementsByClassName('topnav');
    var descendents = ancestor[0].getElementsByTagName('*');

    for(var i = 0; i < descendents.length; i++) {
        if (descendents[i].className === "active" && descendents[i].id != id) {
            descendents[i].className = "inactive";
            break;
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < descendents.length; i++) {
        if (descendents[i].id === id) {
            descendents[i].className = "active";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. Try it with direct getElementById to check if the function is being called properly. I dont see why it should not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have a typo: `descendents[i].id = id` should be `descendents[i].id == id` or better `descendents[i].id === id`.

Second you can't access id with

```
descendents[i].id
```

use

```
descendents[i].getAttribute("id")
```

So the solution:

```
descendents[i].getAttribute("id") === id
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways I've realized a better function to change from inactive to active and viceversa.

**makeActive function:**

```
function makeActive(id)
{
    var active = document.getElementById(id);
    var ancestor = document.getElementsByClassName('topnav');
    var descendents = ancestor[0].getElementsByTagName('*');

    if(active.className === "active") {
        return;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < descendents.length; i++) {
        if (descendents[i].className === "active" && descendents[i].id !== id) {
            descendents[i].className = "inactive";
            break;
        }
    }

    active.className = "active";
}
```